# Kubernetes Google container engine. Configuring Spring Boot HTTPS

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have configured Spring Boot to use HTTPS via application.properties.

```
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

The JKS file is a self signed certificate in / with the web app jar
. My Kubernetes replication controller has the port 8443 configured for the docker image thats running the Spring Boot app.
I have a service configured for the replication controller exposing 8443.

When I go to LoadBalancer Ingress IP :8443 in the browser I get 'no data from server'

What is the correct way of configuring HTTPS load balancing a Spring Boot application on the Google container engine.

Cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this guide and it`s working on my side. https://github.com/mkjelland/spring-boot-postgres-on-k8s-sample

Here you can find spring boot yaml https://github.com/mkjelland/spring-boot-postgres-on-k8s-sample/blob/master/specs/postgres.yml

Plese expose the resource with

```
kubectl expose deployment YOUR_DEPLOYMENT --type=LoadBalancer --port=8443
```